# Number of trees of a specific graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I'm here again with another question regarding graphs. In this case, I am asked to find how many possible graphs are there with set of vertices $S = \{1 \dots 2n \}$ such that there are two connected componentes, each one with $n$ vertices, and each connected component has no cycles (that is, it is a tree). My approach seems right for me, although I would be grateful if someone could give me a confirmation:

First I choose $n$ vertices to form the first connected component: $\binom{2n}{n}$. The remaining vertices belong to the other connected component. Now, for each connected component, given $n$ vertices, there are $n^{n-2}$ possible trees that can be formed (Cayley formula). Then, the final result would be $\binom{2n}{n}\cdot (n^{n-2})^2$. Is this right?

Comment: No, this is not correct. Luckily you just need to multiply a $1/2$ because you are counting twice the graphs, as it is the same to choose a set $A\subseteq [2n]$ that to choose $A^c$, its complement.

Comment: @Phicar, post this comment as an answer, so the OP can select it and the question is marked as answered.

Comment: Right, so the only problem would be that I forgot dividing between $1/2$, right?

Comment: DanielC. Yes, the rest is good. @Sammy Black Done.

Comment: @DanielC. you can check for yourself in the case $n=2$ so the vertex set is $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and the only possible tree on each pair of vertices is the single edge connecting them. In this case, you just have to partition the labels into pairs of pairs: 
$$
\bigl\{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\bigr\}\, 
\bigl\{\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}\bigr\}\, 
\bigl\{\{1, 4\}, \{2, 3\}\bigr\}
$$
and sure enough, there are 
$$
\frac12 \binom{4}{2} 2^{2-2} = \frac12 \cdot 6 \cdot 1 = 3
$$
of them.

Comment: I agree with the number, but wouldn't it be $(2^{2-2})^2$. It gives the same number, but I was wondering if it would be better to mark the square.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I squared it in my head, and then I forgot the square when I typed it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, nice answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Sammy Black:

No, this is not correct. Luckily you just need to multiply a $1/2$ because you are counting twice the graphs, as it is the same to choose a set $A\subseteq [2n]$  that to choose $A^c$, its complement.